Volume of a Cone using Change of Variables
I am having trouble with the following problem.
Let $a,b,c>0$ and let $\Omega$ be the region enclosed by the cone,
$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} =\frac{z^2}{c^2}, 0\leq z\leq c $.
I'm tasked to show that the boundary of $\Omega$ has content zero and then find the 3-volume of the cone. I know I can do this by using the function sending $(r,\theta,z)$ to $(ar\cos(\theta),br\sin(\theta), cz )$ but I am not exactly sure how to proceed. How do I interpret the bounds on $x,y,$ and $z$ and convert them to the cylindrical coordinates?

One way of doing it is;
Let $u=x/a, v=y/b, w=z/c$.
The Jacobian $\frac{d(x,y,z)}{d(u,v,w}$ for this transformation is :
${abc}$
So we are finding the volume bounded by :
$u^2+v^2=w^2$ and multiplying by a factor of $abc$. We are integrating the volume of a cone of a unit height (as bounded above because $z\leq c \implies w\leq1)$ and also bounded below as $z\geq 0, so w\geq 0.$
Then, if u, v are our equivalents to x and y , and w is the equivalent to our z, we use cylindrical polars, i.e
$$r^2=w^2,r=w$$
The bounds of integration will be :
$$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 0\leq r\leq w, 0\leq w\leq1$$
so the volume is:
$$abc\int^1_0\int^w_0\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta drdw=2abc\pi\int^1_0wdw=abc\pi$$
